# How to emit LLVM-IR from Cargo

Tags: rust, llvm-ir, rust-cargo

How can I get cargo to emit LLVM-IR instead of a binary for my project?  I know that you can use the `--emit=llvm-ir` flag in `rustc`, but I've read some Github issues that show it's impossible to pass arbitrary compiler flags to cargo.

Is there any way I can get cargo to emit LLVM-IR directly?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is `cargo rustc` to pass arbitrary compiler flags through Cargo to `rustc`. So I think:

```
cargo rustc -- --emit=llvm-ir
```

is what you want!

This will genarate a `ll` file in `target\debug\deps\`.

Comment: This is what [the alternate playground uses](https://github.com/integer32llc/rust-playground/blob/374c47f24b581f062bfec1de7e5e2dba1c23e9ad/ui/src/sandbox.rs#L234).

Comment: 5 years later, where does this output the IR file?  I just ran it on the guessing game project in The Rust book and I cannot find it.

Comment: Added to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: You should use Jacob's answer instead; a lot easier and less hacky.

Build the project with cargo normally but add on the `-v` flag to show verbose output.  The command will have a result like this:

```
casey@casey-ubuntu:~/Documents/project$ cargo build -v
   Fresh aster v0.22.1
   Fresh num-traits v0.1.34
   Fresh itoa v0.1.1
   ...
Compiling project v0.1.0 (file:///home/casey/Documents/project)
 Running `rustc src/main.rs --crate-name ...`
Finished debug [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 3.54 secs
```

If the command produces no output, make a change somewhere in your project code to trick the compiler into rebuilding it, since it will only rebuild if it detects a change in one of the files.

Copy the `rustc` command from inside the ` markers on the line starting with "Running `rustc..." and append `--emit=llvm-ir` to it.

This will produce a .ll file in your /target/debug folder.