# How do I generate a fully linked, executable LLVM bitcode file from Rust?

Tags: rust, llvm, llvm-ir

I would like to generate a fully linked LLVM bitcode file from Rust source code which could be executed by LLVM IR interpreters such as `lli`. I found solutions such as [one from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/9rnmfs/any_way_to_get_rustc_to_emit_fully_linked_llvm_ir/) and [another one from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004513/how-to-emit-llvm-ir-from-cargo), but they didn't provide enough guidance or could not make fully linked ones.

I hope there could be some detailed guidance here.

Comment: Never used Rust, but I suspect you need to compile your sources with `rustc --emit=llvm-ir` and then use `llvm-link` to link resulting bitcode files into a single one.

Comment: @arrowd I have tried the method on a hello world code, but there is a segmentation fault when running it with `lli` .

Comment: I think you mean fully linked, *interpretable* LLVM bitcode.